# What does width $4$ permutation branching program correspond to?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, circuit-complexity, big-picture, permutations

$L$ can be computed by a family of programs over $S_3$
of polynomial length if and only if $L$ can be computed by a family of $MOD3 ◦ MOD2$ circuits of
polynomial size.

$L$ can be computed by a family of programs over $S_5$
of polynomial length if and only if $L$ can be computed by a family of $NC^1$ circuits of
polynomial size.

How about if $L$ can be computed by a family of programs over $S_4$?

Comment: $S_4$ is solvable with composition factors $C_2$ (3 times) and $C_3$, thus you get again some low-depth combination of MOD2 and MOD3 gates.

Comment: Yeah, I seem to recall that b/c the (unique?) composition series is $1 \unlhd C_2 \times C_2 \unlhd A_4 \unlhd S_4$, that more specifically you get (perhaps a subfamily of) $MOD_2 \circ MOD_3 \circ MOD_2$ circuits.

Comment: How do composition factors relate to the family of programs and their circuits?

Comment: I recommend to look in the following book. Howard Straubing. Finite automata, formal logic, and circuit complexity.